# Change the PDF file styling

Tags: rst2pdf

Would like to change the styling of the generated PDF documents. Have read the manual:

http://ralsina.me/static/manual.pdf

But there is no information that could help. I am modifying the `rst2pdf.css` file, but the changes never take effect.

The files structure looks like this:

[image]

Should I run some command to apply the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stylesheet file in JSON or RSON and use the `-s` command line parameter to apply it.

You can view the default style file by doing:

```
$ rst2pdf --print-stylesheet > rst2pdf_default_styles.style
```

There's more information the manual in the [Styles](https://github.com/rst2pdf/rst2pdf/blob/master/doc/manual.txt#L264) section.